# How to store fetch data into a global variable that you can access later?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, global-variables, fetch-api

My code below is getting all products of a specific product type and the array has data that I want to use in a different function. How would I go about storing the fetched data into a variable that I can use in a different function (I need to add a click event and filter to display additional information from this array elsewhere)

```
const displayProduct = (event) => {
    const info =document.getElementById('info');
    const ul = document.getElementById('makeup-list');
    ul.innerHTML = " ";
    fetch(`https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json/?product_type=${event.target.value}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(data => {
                info.innerHTML += `<li><a href="#" data-id=>${data.name}</a></li>`;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use localStorage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Save in localStorage:

```
ul.innerHTML = " "
 fetch( `https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json/?product_type=${event.target.value}`)
.then(res => res.json())
//iterate
.then(data => {
    localStorage.setItem('myData', data);
 ....
}
```

Get the data in another func:

```
const data = localStorage.getItem('myData');
```